# What's a distributed lock and why use it?

Tags: python, database, web-services, web-applications, memcached

Why do people need a distributed lock?

When the shared resource is protected by it's local machine, does this mean that we do not need a distributed lock?

I mean when **the shared resource is exposed to others by using some kind of api or service, and this api or service is protected using it's local locks**; then we do not need this kind of distributed lock; am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After asking people on [quora](http://www.quora.com/Distributed-Systems/Why-do-people-need-a-distributed-lock/answer/Sean-Owen?__snids__=52301574). I think I got the answer.

Let's say N worker server access a database server. There are two parts here:

1. The database has its own lock methods to protect the data from corrupted by concurrent access of other clients (N work server). This is where a local lock in the database comes out.
2. N worker servers may need some coronation to make sure that they are doing the right thing, and this is application specific. This is where a distributed lock comes out. Say, if two worker server running a same process that drops a table of the database and add some record to the table. The database server can sure guarantee that its internal data is right, but this two process needs a distributed lock to coordinate each other, otherwise, one process will drop another process's table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, if you're exposing your information from the local API through a lock to prevent mutex depending on how the lock is setup your implementation might be that of exactly what a distributed lock is trying to accomplish, but if you haven't developed the API then you'll have to dig into the source of the API to find out if it's a localized or distributed locking system.  Honestly a lock is a lock is a lock, it's attempting to do the same thing no matter what.  The benefit of the distributed lock over a localized one is that you're already accounting for queueing to prevent over access to from clients on expensive cache points.

Comment: Hi, please check my answer, hope it will clarify this.

Comment: @ming.kernel your answer is textbook locks and mutex, as I said, a lock is a lock is a lock.